# Javascript for a suggestion box that pops up as the user scrolls down the screen.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to build an Ajax snippet for a wordpress site that will pop up and suggest the next blog post for that category when the user scrolls down the screen. Is there any jQuery plugins available for this or where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a plugin.  Try something like this jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.nextPost').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.nextPost').fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.nextPost {
  background: lightgray;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nextPost">Next Post</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```